# Array of .Net structure in Matlab

Tags: .net, arrays, matlab

I have a function CreateMCC that needs as an input an array of :

```
public static object CreateMccTemplate(int imageWidth, int imageHeight, int imageResolution, Minutia[] minutiae)
```

I am converting to array it that way:

```
 NETobj = NET.createGeneric('System.Collections.Generic.List',{'BioLab.Biometrics.Mcc.Sdk.Minutia'},length(matlabArray));
 maArray = NET.createGeneric('System.Collections.Generic.List',{'BioLab.Biometrics.Mcc.Sdk.Minutia'},length(matlabArray));
 for i=1:size(matlabArray,1) 
 AddRange(maArray, NET.convertArray(matlabArray(i,:))); 
 end
```

I call it here

```
template1=BioLab.Biometrics.Mcc.Sdk.MccSdk.CreateMccTemplate(300,300,500,maArray);
```

I am getting this error :

```
No method 'AddRange' with matching signature found for class
'System.Collections.Generic.List<BioLab*Biometrics*Mcc*Sdk*Minutia>'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was by creating an array of type of Net structure and filling it with attributs :

```
     maArray = NET.createArray('BioLab.Biometrics.Mcc.Sdk.Minutia',size(matlabArray,1));
       for i=1:size(matlabArray,1)
            NetObject = BioLab.Biometrics.Mcc.Sdk.Minutia();
            NetObject .X =matlabArray(i,1);
            NetObject .Y = matlabArray(i,2);
            NetObject .Direction = matlabArray(i,3);  %filling the attribut
            maArray (i)=L;
       end
template1=BioLab.Biometrics.Mcc.Sdk.MccSdk.CreateMccTemplate(300,300,500,maArray);
```